# Registration Form is not working and does not show any error in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

registration form is not working. When I click on the register button, it reloads the registration form, does not print any error and no data is inserted into the database. Here is the look of the registration form:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPVJ0.png)

**phone.blade code :
**

```
    <!-- REQUIRED CDN  -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/5.0.8-beta.1/inputmask.js" integrity="sha512-aSxEzzrnqlqgASdjAelu/V291nzZNygMSFMJ0h4PFQ+uwdEz6zKkgsIMbcv0O0ZPwFRNPFWssY7gcL2gZ6/t9A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/intlTelInput.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/css/intlTelInput.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/utils.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

@section('scripts')

<style>
    .input-group .iti--allow-dropdown,.phone_input {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $(function () {
        
        var phoneNumbers = $('.phone_input'),
            wrong_number = window.wrong_number_msg,
            required_phone = window.required_phone



        phoneNumbers.each(function () {
            var self = $(this),
                input = self[0],
                type = self.attr('data-type');
                // initialise plugin
                
                var input = document.querySelector("#phone");

                var iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
                // initialCountry: "ma",
                // preferredCountries: ["ma"],
                onlyCountries: ["sa","qa","ma"],
                 
                // autoPlaceholder: "aggressive"

                utilsScript: "../../build/js/utils.js?1678446285328" // just for formatting/placeholders etc
            });

            input.addEventListener("countrychange", function() {
                $('.phone_input').filter(`[data-reflection="${type}"]`).val(iti.getSelectedCountryData().dialCode);
                $('.country_code').val('+'+iti.getSelectedCountryData().dialCode);
            });
            var reset = function() {
                self.parent().next('.invalid-feedback').remove();
                self.parent().removeClass('not-valid');
                self.removeClass("error is-invalid");
            };

            var addError = function(msg) {
                self.addClass('error is-invalid');
                self.parent().addClass('not-valid');
                self.parent().after("<span style='display: block' class=\"invalid-feedback\" role=\"alert\">\n" +
                    " <strong>" + msg + "</strong>\n" +
                    " </span>");
                return false;
            };
            // on blur: validate
            input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
                reset();

                if (self.attr('required')) {
                    if (input.value.trim() == '') {
                        return addError('field is empty')
                    }
                }

                if (input.value.trim() && !iti.isValidNumber()) {
                    return addError('reqierd')
                }
                // run code if verified
            });
            // on keyup / change flag: reset
            input.addEventListener('change', reset);
            input.addEventListener('keyup', reset);
        })


        $(".number-only").keypress(function(event){
            var ewn = event.which;
            if(ewn >= 48 && ewn <= 57) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });


        $(".phone-validation").on("submit", function(evt) {
            var phoneField = $(this).find(".phone_input");
            if (phoneField.hasClass('error')) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                return false
            } else {
                //do the rest of your validations here
                $(this).submit();
            }
        });

    });
</script>


@endsection
```

registr.blade code

```
@extends('adminLte.auth.layout')

<!--css & jq country_code -->
@include('cargo::adminLte.components.inputs.phone')

@section('pageTitle')
    {{ __('Sign In') }}
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="login-box">
  <div class="card card-outline card-primary">
    <div class="card-header text-center">
        <a href="{{ aurl('/') }}" class="mb-12">
          @php
              $model = App\Models\Settings::where('group', 'general')->where('name','login_page_logo')->first();
              $system_logo = App\Models\Settings::where('group', 'general')->where('name','system_logo')->first();
          @endphp
          <img alt="Logo" src="{{ $model->getFirstMediaUrl('login_page_logo') ? $model->getFirstMediaUrl('login_page_logo') : ( $system_logo->getFirstMediaUrl('system_logo') ? $system_logo->getFirstMediaUrl('system_logo') : asset('assets/lte/cargo-logo.svg') ) }}" style="max-width: 88px;max-height: 52px;" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h3 class="widget-title">{{ __('cargo::view.create_a_new_account') }}</h3>
      <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register.request') }}" novalidate="novalidate" id="kt_sign_in_form">
        @csrf
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" required placeholder="{{ __('cargo::view.table.full_name') }}" autocomplete="off" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>
            @error('name')
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {{ $message }}
                </div>
            @enderror
        </div>

        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" required id="email" placeholder="{{ __('cargo::view.table.email') }}" autocomplete="off" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>
            @error('email')
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {{ $message }}
                </div>
            @enderror
        </div>

        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required id="password" placeholder="{{ __('cargo::view.table.password') }}" autocomplete="off" required>
            @error('password')
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {{ $message }}
                </div>
            @enderror
        </div>

        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control @error('national_id') is-invalid @enderror" name="national_id" required placeholder="{{ __('cargo::view.table.owner_national_id') }}" autocomplete="off" value="{{ old('national_id') }}" required autofocus>
            @error('national_id')
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {{ $message }}
                </div>
            @enderror
        </div>

        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control @error('responsible_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="responsible_name" required placeholder="{{ __('cargo::view.table.owner_name') }}" autocomplete="off" value="{{ old('responsible_name') }}" required autofocus>
            @error('responsible_name')
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {{ $message }}
                </div>
            @enderror
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="tel"  id="phone" dir="ltr" autocomplete="off" required  class=" phone_input number-only  form-control inptFielsd @error('responsible_mobile') is-invalid @enderror" name="responsible_mobile" required placeholder="{{ __('cargo::view.table.owner_phone') }}" autocomplete="off"  value="{{ old('responsible_mobile', isset($model) ?$model->country_code.$model->responsible_mobile : '') }}" required autofocus>
            <input type="hidden" class="country_code" name="country_code" value="{{ old('country_code', isset($model) ?$model->country_code : '') }}" data-reflection="phone">
            @error('responsible_mobile')
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {{ $message }}
                </div>
            @enderror
        </div>

        <!--begin::Input group-->
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <select
                class="form-control select-branch  @error('branch_id') is-invalid @enderror"
                name="branch_id"
            >
                <option></option>
                @foreach($branches as $branch)
                    <option value="{{ $branch->id }}"
                        {{ old('branch_id') == $branch->id ? 'selected' : '' }}
                    >{{ $branch->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            @error('branch_id')
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {{ $message }}
                </div>
            @enderror
        </div>
        <!--end::Input group-->

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-8">
            <div class="icheck-primary">
              <input type="checkbox" name="terms_conditions" class="@error('terms_conditions') is-invalid @enderror" id="remember">
              <label for="remember" style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal" required>
                {{ __('cargo::view.terms_and_conditions') }}
              </label>
                @error('terms_conditions')
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ $message }}
                    </div>
                @enderror
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">{{ __('cargo::view.register') }}</button>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
      </form>

      <p class="forgot-password">
        {{ __('cargo::view.already_have_an_account') }}
        <!--begin::Link-->
            <a href="{{ route('login') }}">
                {{ __('cargo::view.login') }}
            </a>
        <!--end::Link-->
      </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card-body -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.card -->
</div>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/lte') }}/plugins/select2/css/select2.min.css">


<style type="text/css" media="all">

  .input-group .iti--allow-dropdown {
        width: 100% !important;
    }

  body {
    background: #FFF !important;
  }
  div.login-box {
    width: 500px;
  }
  div.login-box div.card {
    padding: 2.75rem 3.75rem!important;
    box-shadow: 0 .1rem 1rem .25rem rgba(0,0,0,.05)!important;
    border-radius: 0.475rem!important;
    border: 0 none !important;
  }
  div.login-box div.card div.card-body {
    padding: 24px 0 0 0 !important;
  }
  div.login-box div.card-header {
    padding: 0 !important;
    border: 0 none !important;
    margin-bottom: 24px !important;
  }
  p.forgot-password {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
  }

  .widget-title {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 auto 24px !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    position: relative !important;
    display: block !important;
    font-size: 22px !important;
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
  }

  .form-control {
    height: calc(50px + 2px) !important;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
  }

  .input-group:not(.has-validation) > .form-control:not(:last-child), .input-group:not(.has-validation) > .custom-select:not(:last-child), .input-group:not(.has-validation) > .custom-file:not(:last-child) .custom-file-label::after
  {
    border-top-right-radius: 0 !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0 !important;
  }

  @media (max-width: 767px)
  {
    html, body {
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
      -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
      touch-action: manipulation;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      overflow-x: hidden !important;
      width: unset !important;
      height: unset !important;
    }
    body { min-height: unset !important; }
    div.login-box {
      width: 100% !important;
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
    }
    div.login-box div.card {
      padding: 40px 24px !important;
      background: none transparent !important;
      box-shadow: none !important;

    }
  }
    .select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
        height: 100% !important;
    }
    .select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow {
        height: 100% !important;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/lte') }}/plugins/select2/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.select-branch').select2({
        placeholder: "{{ __('cargo::view.table.choose_branch') }}",
        width: '100%',
    })
</script>
@endsection
```

I don't know what to try

Comment: @akami have you checked the controller function through `dd()` or any action you've performed?

Comment: Can you show your controller?

Comment: So the thing is that you need to create a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, try to open up your chrome dev tools when posting thr form. Check `console` and `network` tab when posting the form. Check laravel.log for errors